# How to subtract result of 2 queries grouped by a field

Tags: sql

I have a table in this form:

```
id  year type  amount
 1  2015   in      10
 2  2015  out       5
 3  2016   in      20
 4  2016  out       1
 ...
```

The followin query will give me the sum of the amount of type = 'in' grouped by year:

```
SELECT year, sum(amount)
FROM table
WHERE type = in
GROUP BY year
```

How am I going to get the following result?

```
year sum(in) sum(out) "in-out"
2015     10       5        5
2016     20       1       19
```

sum(in) is the sum of the 'amount' where type='in'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a CASE statement to handle the values of `type`.

```
SELECT year,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'in' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS sum_in,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'out' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS sum_out,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'in' THEN amount ELSE -amount END) AS in_out
    FROM table
    GROUP BY year;
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem! 
(I used IIF(condition, valueiftrue, valueiffalse) instead of CASE because I am on Access...)